# Вывод видео с карты видео захвата в тег <video> html?

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть устройство, к нему подключаем **карту видео захвата** (пока с ней, но в идеале напрямую через `vga`). Устройство и карта на стороне клиента. Как мне вывести видео в тег `<video>`?

Правильно ли я себе представляю работу такого ресурса:

- Есть клиент, на котором устанавливается сервер
- Есть удалённый сервер(ресурс), на котором есть `html` элемент для проигрывания онлайн видео
- При переходе клиента в броузере на удалённый сервер он подгружает инструмент для просмотра онлайн видео (`html страницу`)
- Загруженная страница с удалённого сервера делает запрос к локальному серверу (сервер на стороне клиента, например OpenServer) по определённому порту (Например: `127.0.0.1:3333`) при помощи библиотеки `hls.js`
- Локальный сервер отдаёт файлы `.m3u8`, предварительно закодировав их.

В итоге видео идущее с **карты захвата** можно просматривать в **режиме онлайн**.

> UPD Накидал `скриптик` с `html`:

Выводит видео с карты видео захвата **AverMedia DVD EZMaker 7 C039**. Операционная система **Ubuntu 18.04**. Работает только в Chrome. В FF выдаёт ошибку:

> MediaStreamError { name: "AbortError", message: "Starting video failed", constraint: "", stack: "" }

```js
    const video = document.querySelector('#videoElement');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: true,
    }).then(stream => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
    }).catch( error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

```css
#container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
video{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Плата захвата на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: @eri на клиенте.

Comment: Давайте обсудим. Откуда пхп на клиенте?

Comment: Нажмите кнопку редактировать и уточните вопрос

Comment: @eri Согласен. Как тогда видео то грузануть? Клиенты не особо напрягаться должны. Т.е. открыли адрес и всё подтянулось. Ну пару диалоговых окон.

Comment: Каких окон?) давайте сначала распишите откуда берется видео и кому передается

Comment: Как определяется плата захвата в системе?

Comment: @eri Как карта видео захвата. К ней есть штатные дрова.

Comment: А кому и зачем видео передаётся-то?

Comment: @andreymal мне не нужен стрим) Мне нужно выводить изображение в своё приложение, к которому написан свой функционал. За прогу спасибо. Не знал про такую.

Comment: Ну тогда вроде не должно быть проблемы без всяких извращений с hls.js просто взять и подключиться к карте захвата, как к веб-камере https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

Comment: @doox911 нет, это всё в пределах одной html-страницы. Ну, если карта захвата вообще увидится браузером или где вы там своё приложение делаете

Comment: @andreymal Я так понял, что если есть видео поток, то мы можем его отловить так (пишут что для вебки так): `navigator.getUserMedia('video, audio', function(localMediaStream) {...` ?

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно организовать потоковую трансляцию на стороне web сервера.

Получаете с видеопоток с карты видеозахвата и отправляете его в сеть через web сервер. По другому в Вашем случае никак.

К сожалению, лично я не знаю готовых продуктов, которые поддерживали бы потоковую передачу с карт видеозахвата. Вполне вероятно, что всё необходимое ПО Вам придётся написать самостоятельно.

Это если плата на стороне сервера.

Если устройство на клиенте, ищите как "поженить" "видеозахват" с WebRTC. Или развернуть на клиенте ПО с web интерфейсом (дальше см. написанное про сервер).

Comment: Т.е. пользователь переходит на сайт и я должен как то отыскать у него передачу видео потока?

Comment: Зачем? Стриминг видео идёт через браузер обычно.

Comment: А киньте ссылочками) А требуется ли на стороне пользователя дополнительное программное обеспечение?

Comment: ПО на стороне клиента не нужно. Ссылки гуглите "ffmpeg", "HLS".

Comment: Так у него плата на клиенте

Comment: Если плата на клиенте, то гуглить про WebRTC.

Comment: @Streletz вэб ртц это когда видео отдаешь. Его ещё захватить надо.

Comment: Согласен, но WebRTC поддерживает и захват видео. Только мы не знаем как железка автора определяется в системе и куда он это видео собирается стримить. Вообще у ТС задача далеко не самая стандартная. ИМХО, всё, что мы с Вами можем сделать, это накидать теоретически возможных подходов к её решению. По-хорошему здесь надо копать...

Answer (score 4):

Ffmpeg стрим в hls в папку www. Создается плэйлист и фрагменты видео рядом. Ссылку на плейлист в тег видео.

Так как карта захвата на клиенте, то надо запустить ffmpeg в hls на клиенте. Заклинание это в одну строку, но есть пара вариантов. Дальше нужен на клиенте вэб сервер, чтоб это видео отдать в браузер. Если сайта не будет, то можно попробовать через file://

Средствами php только если снимать jpeg и слать в mjpeg.

Comment: Не совсем понял ответа. Видео должно быть онлайн.

Comment: Как удалить ответ с мобильного приложения?)

Comment: Т.е. на винду покатит `Openserver` и через него отправлять видео?